# Dired: One confirmation for all selected files and directories

Tags: emacs, dired

Use-case:

1. Mark for deletion target files and directories at the dired buffer;
2. Execute 'dired-do-flagged-delete' (type 'x');

**Result:** I'm asked about confirmation for every non-empty directory being removed.

**Question:** is there easy way to say 'yes' one time and get all of the marked stuff (including non-empty directories) removed?

I googled that it's possible to set *'dired-recursive-deletes'* to *'always'* but that doesn't protect me from accidental 'delete' processing (e.g. mistyped 'x' while wrong directory is marked).

I understand that it's possible to customize emacs via lisp injections but I don't know that language so far, that's the reason why I'm asking whether there is other solution.

Comment: When you press `x`, you are prompted whether or not to delete all the marked files.  With the `top` setting (default), you're prompted for each directory individually, and with the `always` setting you're not prompted (other than the initial prompt).  Are you asking for two prompts - the initial one, which lists everything, and a second prompt which only lists the directories?

Comment: I'm asking about single confirmation for 'delete all'.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you found your answer but didn't try it.

```
(setq dired-recursive-deletes 'always)
```

And you'll only get a single prompt, asking if you want to delete the *n* items, and you'll get a list of them.  You will not be further prompted for the directories.

Comment: Thanks, was misguided by the property description.

Comment: You probably want this for copying directories too: `(setq dired-recursive-copies 'always)`